# Finding the multiples of a number that satisfy the question.

Tags: calculus, algorithms

Two numbers multiply to equal 200. Find the numbers such that the difference between the square root of one number and the reciprocal of the other is minimized.

Having a tough time working around this problem, I'm having some trouble.

Comment: Integers, or real numbers?

Comment: The question doesn't specify, let's go with real numbers.

Comment: Difference or absolute value of difference? And if difference which goes first? A standard algebra/calculus way would be to let one number be $x$. Then the other is $200/x$ and its reciprocal is $x/200$.

Comment: Your title and your question don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one number is $x$, the other is $\frac{200}x$, so we want to minimize the distance between $\sqrt x$ and $\frac x{200}$. We can in fact make these expressins equal: $\sqrt x=\frac x{200}\iff x=200^2=40000$ (and the other factor is $\frac1{200}$).